# How to create a Django group and assign the group to certain models?

Tags: python, django

I would like to know how to create groups in django and assign the group to certain models. How can I do this?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization

Answer (score 2):

You create a model for your `Group`:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    # …
```

next you can define a `ForeignKey` from a model to that `Group`:

```
class OtherModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    group = models.ForeignKey(
        'Group'
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='other_models'
    )
    # …
```

Next you can create a group, for example:

```
grp = Group.objects.create(name='name-of-the-group')
```

and then make an `OtherModel` instance that refers to that group:

```
item = OtherModel.objects.create(
    name='name-of-the-model',
    group=grp
)
```

Comment: The problem is, I want to assign the group to a default django user model, but dont know how to modify it

Comment: @Serket: Django's user model already has groups: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/#group-model it uses this for its permission model.

Comment: then how exactly do I use that model?

Comment: @Serket: you import it from `from django.contrib.auth.models import Group`. This is a simple model, just like other models (and just like the `User` model), so you can do anything with that `Group` model, you do with a custom model.

Comment: and then what do I do?

Comment: @Serket: you can add `ForeignKey`s to that model, create new groups, etc. Since you do not really specify a "use case", it is unclear to me exactly what you aim to ahchieve.